# Asp.Net GridView with two rows in footer

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

Is there a way to have two rows in GridView footer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the links

[more than 1 row footer in gridview](https://forums.asp.net/t/1182911.aspx)

[Adding a new row at the footer of a GridView](https://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/664747-adding-new-row-footer-gridview)

[How to extend existing GridView control in ASP.NET 2.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20160204011653/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paraga/archive/2005/12/13/503081.aspx)

[How to simply modify a GridView](http://fredrik.nsquared2.com/ViewPost.aspx?PostId=429)

[Add a summary of a column to the end of the GridView](https://web.archive.org/web/20100605161552/http://fredrik.nsquared2.com:80/viewpost.aspx?PostID=378)

[Multiple footers inbetween gridview](https://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/216173-Multiple-footers-inbetween-gridview.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

See this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/paraga/asp-net-2-0-extending-gridview-control-to-display-extra-footer-rows), ASP.NET 2.0 - Extending GridView control to display extra Footer Rows

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for -1, what about the accepted answer, it has 6 links! On a answer that is 4 years old!

Comment: When reviewing posts, I don't see other existing answers. The invalidity of other posts does not make yours any more valid. And it wasn't my downvote.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the accepted answer has 6 links. Agreed mine isn't the best answer as it is a link only. I am only pointing out that your comment applies to the accepted answer as well.

Comment: During the review process, if an answer is flagged, I see a review panel that contains the question and the flagged answer. I see no other answers, because other answers don't matter. Regardless of whether someone else has violated the "link-only answer" rule or not, your post still violates that rule. If the accepted answer was the word "BAZINGA" pasted a thousand times, it still wouldn't change the fact that you answer is still pretty much just a link.